# How do I split a String of nine characteres with a regular expression in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `String` called pin with a value like: `123456789` and I need to do the following:

**What I have:**

```
String pin = "123456789";
```

What I want after the operation:

```
String result = "123-456-789";
```

**what I'm doing right now:**

```
  String _formatReferenceCode(String code){
    final list = code.split("");
    String part1 = list.sublist(0, 3).join();
    String part2 = list.sublist(3, 6).join();
    String part3 = list.sublist(6, 9).join();
    return "$part1-$part2-$part3";
  }

String result = _formatReferenceCode(referenceCode);

// it prints: "123-456-789"
```

My current code works, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an option you can use regexp [`negative lookahead`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
  String _formatReferenceCode(String code) {
    final Pattern pattern = RegExp(r'(.{3})(?!$)');
    return code.replaceAllMapped(pattern, (m) => '${m[0]}-');
  }
```

Comment: As for me this regexp does not match the last 3 digits.

Comment: Ok. I just tested the regular expression here https://regex101.com/ and I saw unexpected results.

Comment: This one seems the best option. Thank you @Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the power of regular expressions and method [replaceAllMapped](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) of String class

```
final pin = '123456789';
// Divide PIN by 3 digits (\d{3}) and place result to match group
final regexp = RegExp(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})');
// Call method which returns substitution
final result = pin.replaceAllMapped(
    regexp, (match) => '${match[1]}-${match[2]}-${match[3]}');
```